# Why Are My Nameservers Directed to Njalla?

Tags: dns

first of all, I am not very knowledgeable about these web things. So please keep in mind that I might be wrong about anything, I am just expressing my thoughts and experience here.

I bought my domain from [njal.la](https://njal.la) last year. I have been using them for over a year. It was all good until I couldn't renew my ssl due to malfunctioning nameservers, then trying to check the nameservers in my njalla account but being unable to log in, after that checking it via a dns checker website and seeing that they replaced my nameservers with their own nameservers, and then finally reading people's comments on trustpilot nearly all of which are about domain stealing issues.

So I suspect my domain might have been stolen by njalla, where I bought it from. Am I correct? If so, what are my options? What can I do?

I have tried contacting njalla but haven't heard back from them yet.